# Return all collection items at once to function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with the output off a collection. What the sub does is go into an XML file and retrieves multiple data sets (name + ranking number). Ranking numbers only go from 1 - 25. It will filter out the name and only gives the ranking number.

What the function does is converting a string of numbers into a more readable overview, for example
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 20, 22, 23, 24 is converted to 1-3, 5-6, 20, 22-24. All the numbers in the first string have to be seperated by a "," hence the `Coll.add ","`

Now I know how to get the data with `for each item in Coll` but I'm unable to get all the values in 1 string. Maybe collections is not the ideal functions for this?

So the question is how can I retrieve the full collaction as string as is? Because everthing is in the right order and with the `add ","` my collection is complete.

```
    Dim Coll As Collection
    Set Coll = New Collection

    Set NameNod = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Report/Results/Name/elt/NameId/text()")

For i = 0 To NameNod.Length - 1

    Ranking = Right(NameNod(i).NodeValue, 2) 'returns only the ranking number

    Coll.Add Ranking
    Coll.Add "," 

Next
```

```
Function IntoRanges(aString As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String
    Dim NextBit As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Items As Variant
    Items = Split(aString, Delimiter)

    IntoRanges = Items(0)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Items) - 1
        If Val(Items(i)) + 1 = Val(Items(i + 1)) Then
            NextBit = "-" & Val(Items(i + 1))
        Else
            If NextBit = vbNullString Then
                IntoRanges = IntoRanges & Delimiter & Val(Items(i + 1))

            Else
                IntoRanges = IntoRanges & NextBit & Delimiter & Val(Items(i + 1))
                NextBit = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    IntoRanges = IntoRanges & NextBit
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a collection you could build the string immediately

```
    Dim Coll As Collection
    Set Coll = New Collection

    Set NameNod = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Report/Results/Name/elt/NameId/text()")

    Dim aString As String
    For i = 0 To NameNod.Length - 1

        ranking = Right(NameNod(i).NodeValue, 2) 'returns only the ranking number

'        Coll.Add ranking
'        Coll.Add ","
        aString = aString & ranking & ","
    Next
    ' remove the last comma
    aString = Left(aString, Len(aString) - 1)
```

**PS** If you want to stay with the collection I would suggest to remove `coll.add ","` and use the following function

```
Function intoString(col As Collection, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim res As String
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        res = res & col.Item(i) & Delimiter
    Next i
    res = Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
    intoString = res
End Function
```

And your code would look like that then

```
        Dim Coll As Collection
        Set Coll = New Collection

        Set NameNod = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Report/Results/Name/elt/NameId/text()")

    For i = 0 To NameNod.Length - 1

        Ranking = Right(NameNod(i).NodeValue, 2) 'returns only the ranking number

        Coll.Add Ranking
        'Coll.Add "," 

    Next

   Debug.Print IntoRanges(intoString(Coll))
```

Comment: Great, both options work but for the first I had some bugs where the `aString` values of the previous loop would still be in the memory. So I was busy fixing these and then I saw that you added some extra info. The second options works perfectly without any adjustments. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Dictonary` object, which lets you retrieve both a final string or an array

```
 Dim NameNod As Object
    Set NameNod = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/Report/Results/Name/elt/NameId/text()")

    Dim myString As String
    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 0 To NameNod.Length - 1
            Ranking = Right(NameNod(i).NodeValue, 2) 'returns only the ranking number
            .Add Ranking, 0
        Next
        myString = Join(.keys, ",")
        myArr = .keys
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use a delimiter (e.g. a dash) for ranges and skip intermediate values you could use this function:

```
Function IntoString(ByVal coll As Collection, Optional nxtDelimiter As String = ",", Optional rngDelimiter As String = "-") As String
Dim i As Long
Dim IStr As String
IStr = coll.Item(1)
For i = 2 To coll.Count - 1
    If coll.Item(i) <> coll.Item(i - 1) + 1 Then
        IStr = IStr & nxtDelimiter & coll.Item(i)
    Else
        If coll.Item(i) <> coll.Item(i + 1) - 1 Then IStr = IStr & rngDelimiter & coll.Item(i)
    End If
Next i
If coll.Item(coll.Count) = coll.Item(coll.Count - 1) + 1 Then
    IStr = IStr & rngDelimiter & coll.Item(coll.Count)
Else
    IStr = IStr & nxtDelimiter & coll.Item(coll.Count)
End If
IntoString = IStr
End Function
```

But keep in mind that your collection should only contain the values (not the delimiters).